# Passing mapped data to another component as props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

[image]How do i pass this mapped data, which changes after a certain interval, to another component as props

```
        <View>
            {data.prices && data.prices.map((prices, index) => {
                return (
                    <ListItem
                        key={index}
                        onPress = {() => navigation.navigate('CreateAlertScreen',)}
                        bottomDivider>
                        <ListItem.Content>
                            <ListItem.Title>
                                {data.prices[index].instrument}        
                                {data.prices[index].closeoutAsk}        
                                {data.prices[index].closeoutBid}
                            </ListItem.Title>
                        </ListItem.Content>
                    </ListItem>
                )
            })
            }
        </View>
```

Comment: What do you mean by ```another component```? Please elaborate more on your setup and to which component you want data to be sent as props

Comment: By another component i mean another screen that will need to use that data. For example: CreatealertScreen for a stock when that selected stock reaches a certain price.

Comment: Depends on your set up, not very much clear to me, of updating prices and check for prices of stock, you can always send data to another screen like ```navigation.navigate('CreateAlertScreen',prices)```.

Comment: `item.instrument` worked

Comment: Is it possible to pass the changing data to` CreateAlertScreen` and have the data change the way its changing in this Screen

Comment: You may have to use context or redux to manage that but I think that's another question. So ```navigation.navigate('CreateAlertScreen',item.instrument)``` works for you? May I put that in an answer?

Comment: Yes the data is passed but doesn't dynamically change

Comment: So how can i do it using context

Comment: @Eddieed can please show us the values of data so that we can reproduce the problem ?

Comment: Basically, its currency pairs with their bid and ask prices. Let me attach a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of the index you can use item like this

```
        <View>
            {data.prices && data.prices.map((item, index) => {
                return (
                    <ListItem
                        key={index}
                        onPress = {() => navigation.navigate('CreateAlertScreen',)}
                        bottomDivider>
                        <ListItem.Content>
                            <ListItem.Title>
                                {item.instrument}        
                                {item.closeoutAsk}        
                                {item.closeoutBid}
                            </ListItem.Title>
                        </ListItem.Content>
                    </ListItem>
                )
            })
            }
        </View>
```

Comment: How does it answer the question? Isn't the same OP already has?

Comment: Both of them work. How do i then pass the above dynamic data as props to another component

Comment: I used a modal instead and it worked perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can easily pass map data to another component if you make your code like this

```
function Price(props) {
  const { navigation, price } = props;
  
  return (
    <ListItem onClick={() => navigation.navigate("CreateAlertScreen")}>
      <ListItem.Content>
        <ListItem.Title>
          {price.instrument}
          {price.closeoutAsk}
          {price.closeoutBid}
        </ListItem.Title>
      </ListItem.Content>
    </ListItem>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <View>
      {data.prices.map((price, i) => {
        // Simply return a component for each item of the map
        // So you can easily pass map data as props
        return <Price key={i} navigation={navigation} price={price} />;
      })}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Click the codesandbox link for the demonstation on this will work

https://codesandbox.io/s/passingmapdataascomponent-fptum?file=/src/App.js

Ask me questions if you need to.

Comment: I don't think navigation should be a prop. It feels like more of a global thing.

Comment: @ElectricShadow Yes, It could be navigation is not a prop. But for the purpose of simulating or reproducing the problem it still work.

Answer (score -1):

Note: If you are using the LTS version of NodeJS, you will not be able to use the nullish coalescing operator as I have used it here. You will have to find a workaround, like replaceint `a ?? b` with `a === null || a === undefined ? b : a`.

```
class DataView extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.prices = props.prices ?? [];
  }
  render() {
    return <View>
      {this.prices.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <ListItem
            key={index}
            onPress = {() => navigation.navigate('CreateAlertScreen',)}
            bottomDivider={true}>
            <ListItem.Content>
              <ListItem.Title>
                {item.instrument}        
                {item.closeoutAsk}        
                {item.closeoutBid}
              </ListItem.Title>
            </ListItem.Content>
          </ListItem>
        )
      })}
    </View>;
  }
}
```

With this code, you could do something like:

```
<DataView prices={data.prices}/>
```